# Use global Vue 3 plugins in Storybook stories?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook

How can I use a Vue 3 plugin in Storybook stories?

For example, I use FormKit to create form elements in my components.

FormKit is rigged globally in my main.ts like so:

```
import { plugin, defaultConfig } from '@formkit/vue'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(plugin, defaultConfig)
```

but this file isn't used by Storybook... so how can I do the same for Storybook?

Comment: `app` can be imported from `@storybook/vue3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find documentation here:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/47f753f5e8d084b4d544cf1ec76077a9382aa6b2/app/vue3

I learned that you are able to access the app created by Storybook in `.storybook/preview.js` by importing it from @storybook/vue3.

Example is copied from above link:

```
// .storybook/preview.js

import { app } from '@storybook/vue3';

app.use(MyPlugin);
app.component('my-component', MyComponent);
app.mixin({
  /* My mixin */
});
```

Comment: storybook 6.4 - working!

Comment: Not working with v7 release

Answer (score 6):

Since storybook 7, things have changed a little and emelin's answer won't work. in order to access app instance you should import `setup` instead and `app` would be passed as a parameter fed to setup's callback, here is an example:

```
// .storybook/preview.js
import { MotionPlugin } from "@vueuse/motion";
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3";

setup((app) => {
    app.use(MotionPlugin);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for v7+

Comment: If you do as me and use mixin you can't do as before and use `mixin({// your mixins})` your need to do it like thus
`// .storybook/preview.js
import { MotionPlugin } from "@vueuse/motion";
import myMixin1 from "@mixin/MyMixin1";
import myMixin2 from "@mixin/MyMixin2";
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3";

setup((app) => {
    app.use(MotionPlugin)
      .mixin(myMixin1)
      .mixin(myMixin2);
});`

Answer (score 2):

The new release of Storybook introduces the use of `setup` instead of `app`. You can find more information about this change in the [migration guide](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#vue3-replaced-app-export-with-setup).

If you are currently using an older version (such as version 6), you can follow the solution provided in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72110042/15187315).

In summary, the changes are as follows:

For versions before 7:

```
import { app } from '@storybook/vue3';
import Button from './Button.vue';
app.component('GlobalButton', Button);
app.use(MyPlugin);
```

For version 7 and later:

```
import { setup } from '@storybook/vue3';
import Button from './Button.vue';

setup((app) => {
  app.component('GlobalButton', Button);
  app.use(MyPlugin);
});
```

Please make sure to adapt your code accordingly based on the version of Storybook you are using.