# How can I create a project in vue 3 with storybook and primevue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, storybook, primevue

I want to create stories with primevue components, but I can't. I'm using the latest version of storybook, primevue, vite and vue. I'm also using Typescript.

I have this component:

```
<template>
  <button type="button" :class="classes" @click="onClick" :style="style">{{ label }} </button>
  <InputText label="test" v-model="value"></InputText>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import './button.css'
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{
  /**
   * The label of the button
   */
  label: string,
  /**
   * primary or secondary button
   */
  primary?: boolean,
  /**
   * size of the button
   */
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large',
  /**
   * background color of the button
   */
  backgroundColor?: string,

}>(), { primary: false });
const value = ref(null)
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'click', id: number): void;
}>();

const classes = computed(() => ({
  'storybook-button': true,
  'storybook-button--primary': props.primary,
  'storybook-button--secondary': !props.primary,
  [`storybook-button--${props.size || 'medium'}`]: true,
}));

const style = computed(() => ({
  backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor
}));

const onClick = () => {
  emit("click", 1)
};

</script>
```

This is my Main.ts

```
import './assets/main.css'
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(PrimeVue)
app.component('InputText', InputText)
app.mount('#app')
```

Changing the main.ts to this, doesn´t work either:

```
import './assets/main.css'
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3";

setup((app) => {
    app.use(PrimeVue, {ripple:true});
    app.component('InputText', InputText)
});
```

And this is the warning of the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: InputText
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <Button primary=false label="Button" size="small"  ... > 
  at <Anonymous> 
  at <App>
```

I expect to se the InputText in the storybook and create custom components.

This is the project where I'm having the error.
https://github.com/xiscohv/primevue-ts-storybook

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . You're supposed to either register comps globally for the app like that https://primevue.org/installation/#usage or import them explicitly like that https://primevue.org/inputtext/#import

Comment: I have registered the comps globally for the app and still gives me this error

Comment: In which way? The question doesn't reflect this

Comment: Sorry If the question is not very accurate, this is my first post. This is the repository with the files:
https://github.com/xiscohv/primevue-ts-storybook
I don't see where the error is...

Comment: main.ts isn't involved in storybook setup, it has its own app instance, you need to set up app plugins, etc separately there

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098527/use-global-vue-3-plugins-in-storybook-stories

Comment: I change to this and is giving me the same error:
import './assets/main.css'
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3";

setup((app) => {
    app.use(PrimeVue, {ripple:true});
    app.component('InputText', InputText)
});

Comment: "Changing the main.ts to this" - Make sure this code is executed in SB. Notice that it's not main.ts in the linked question. As I said, main.ts isn't involved, SB is unaware of your app structure.

Comment: Yess!! That was it, I added what I had in my main.ts and added to the ./storybook/preview.ts and it works! Thank you

Comment: Glad it was simple to solve

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the file .storybook/preview.ts has fixed it:

```
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3"
import "primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css"

setup((app) => {
    app.use(PrimeVue, {ripple:true});
    app.component('InputText', InputText)
})
```